# Get list of channels subscribed by user using userid, without authorization

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-channels

Previously we are using GData V2 api to get list of channels subscribed by user using userid as follows,

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userid/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json&max-results=50

But in V3 api, to get list of channels subscribed by user, authorization is compulsory, anyone know any other approach for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In V3 Api you can get list of subscriptions by using channel id of that user.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&channelId=*channelid*&maxResults=20&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: For this to work you need to have to have the channel having the list of subscriptions set to public.

Answer (score 1):

In V3 API, if you have the access token, and the channel id. Make a GET request like

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&channelId=**channel_id**&access_token=**access_token**&maxResults=**max_results_between_0_to_50_default_5**
```

I'm not an expert or anything, but I'm getting the result correctly now for what I'm working on.

**Edit:**

 
@prasad's answer is correct though, but the request will not work with api_key.  Just replaced his api_key with access_token.

Comment: Hey, Thanks, it's helped me a lot.